# load and cache remote image in background thread

Tags: iphone

I am working on an iPhone app.In this app I need to display many images in uitableview.I am able to load the image in the background thread.But can anyone suggest how can I cache the downloaded image in background thread.I am able to cache the image but it is happenening in foreground not in background.Thats why the UI gets blocked until the caching completes.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can try [SDWebImage Cache](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), it is very easy to use and it will do caching part.

The caching interval is set to one week, you can check it in SDImageCache.m.